# totalling rows for distinct values in SQL

Tags: sql

I haven't had much experience with SQL and it strikes me as a simple question, but after an hour of searching I still can't find an answer...

I have a table that I want to add up the totals for based on ID - e.g:

```
-------------
ID   Quantity  
1        30  
2        11  
1         4  
1         3  
2        17  
3        16  
.............
```

After summing the table should look something like this:

```
-------------
ID   Quantity
1        37
2        28
3        16
```

I'm sure that I need to use the DISTINCT keyword and the SUM(..) function, but I can only get one total value for all unique value combinations in the table, and not separate ones like above.  Help please :)

Comment: Instead of searching for an answer to something you think is simple (you're correct, it is), why not *study* the technology?

Comment: you don't need distinct, try 'group by'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select ID, Sum(Quantity) from YourTable
Group by ID
```

You can find here some resources to learn more about "Group by": http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: @user2521119: the link isn't really a good place to learn SQL. w3fools is known to be full of errors.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: one thing is sure, there are no errors in the page I shared :)

Comment: Well, [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_wildcards.asp) is wrong, and [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp) and [this](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_select_into.asp)

Comment: "*[charlist]  Sets and ranges of characters to match*" - SQL (the query language) only supports `_` and `%` as wildcard characters

Comment: MySQL doesn't support sets and ranges of characters , but SQL server does. And as the examples are using Northwind SQL server sample database, it does make sens

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT ID, SUM(QUANTITY) FROM TABLE1 GROUP BY ID ORDER BY ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select ID, Sum(Quantity) AS Quantity 
from table1
Group by ID
```

Replace table1 with name of the table.

Answer (score 0):

Just posting a complete answer that aliases the column and orders the results:

```
SELECT ID, SUM(Quantity) as [Quantity]
FROM TableName
GROUP BY ID
ORDER BY ID
```